# Prevent IE from refreshing page – iframe _top

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, hash, refresh

How can I prevent IE from updating the page? I want it to behave like FF, SF & C. Since it's the same page it should not upload...

**Parent page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the parent page. I don't want this page to reload in IE when the link in the iframe is clicked, since it break our javascript. I only want the "hash" to change.</p>
    <iframe src="http://example.com/iframepage.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Iframe page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the iframe page. The URL is the same as the parent page + anchorlink. When I klick this link in IE the page refresch and the javascript breaks. In FF, SF & C it doesn’t "refresh" page…</p>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/test.html#test1" target="_top">test1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oops. The HTML disipeard when I was posting.

URL of parent page: http://www.example.com/test.html

<a>Link in the iframe: a href="http://www.example.com/test.html#test1" target="_top">test1</a>

Answer (score -1):

try this code for all browsers

```
var src = document.getElementById("mydiv").getAttribute("src");

if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")  // ie iframe reload fix
    document.getElementById("mydiv").setAttribute("src","");

$SQuery(mydiv).setAttribute("src",src); // this will not save it in history ;)
```